# An association from the table refers to an unmapped class: System.Decimal

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

There are linkValues accociated with A those are Decimal Value.

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Decimal> LinkValues { get; set; }
}


public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("A_Id");

        HasManyToMany<Decimal>(x => x.Links)
                .Table("A_Link_Value_Map")
                .ParentKeyColumn("A_Id")
                .ChildKeyColumn("Link_Value")
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

I am getting a issue "An association from the table A_Link_Value_Map refers to an unmapped class: System.Decimal". Anyone have any idea or could you please give your thoughts for same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping `HasManyToMany` would expect to have *entity/object* not `ValueType` - on the other side of many-to-many. Also many-to-many reuires the pairing table.

The mapping we need here is the `HasMany` and for *ValueType* like `Decimal` we need `.Element()` mapping:

```
HasMany(x => x.Links)
    .Table("A_Link_Value_Map")
    .KeyColumn("A_Id")
    .Element("Link_Value") // Value Type would be an Element
    .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

Comment: Great to see that, enjoy NHibernate ;)